GeoPandas error: AttributeError: You can only set the value of existing options
When I try to set pyogrio globally like this:
gpd.options.io_engine = "pyogrio"

I get the error:
AttributeError: You can only set the value of existing options

This however works:
test = gpd.read_file(r"path\to\file.gpkg", engine='pyogrio')


What causes this problem, and how can I set this option globally?
I'm using a conda env with python= 3.10.14 and geopandas=0.12.2 within a jupyter notebook.

The global option was only introduced in geopandas 0.14... so you should update geopandas to be able to use it.
Reference: geopandas PR3008

Oh, this is interesting, as I was using it before. It only stopped working since about two weeks ago.
